# Suggestions for doing async I/O with Task Parallel Library

Tags: asynchronous, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have some high performance file transfer code which I wrote in C# using the Async Programming Model (APM) idiom (eg, `BeginRead`/`EndRead`).  This code reads a file from a local disk and writes it to a socket.

For best performance on modern hardware, it's important to keep more than one outstanding I/O operation in flight whenever possible.  Thus, I post several `BeginRead` operations on the file, then when one completes, I call a `BeginSend` on the socket, and when that completes I do another `BeginRead` on the file.  The details are a bit more complicated than that but at the high level that's the idea.

I've got the APM-based code working, but it's very hard to follow and probably has subtle concurrency bugs.  I'd love to use TPL for this instead.  I figured `Task.Factory.FromAsync` would just about do it, but there's a catch.

All of the I/O samples I've seen (most particularly the `StreamExtensions` class in the Parallel Extensions Extras) assume one read followed by one write.  This won't perform the way I need.

I can't use something simple like `Parallel.ForEach` or the Extras extension `Task.Factory.Iterate` because the async I/O tasks don't spend much time on a worker thread, so Parallel just starts up another task, resulting in potentially dozens or hundreds of pending I/O operations; way too much! You can work around that by `Wait`ing on your tasks, but that causes creation of an event handle (a kernel object), and a blocking wait on a task wait handle, which ties up a worker thread.  My APM-based implementation avoids both of those things.

I've been playing around with different ways to keep multiple read/write operations in flight, and I've managed to do so using continuations that call a method that creates another task, but it feels awkward, and definitely doesn't feel like idiomatic TPL.

Has anyone else grappled with an issue like this with the TPL?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about too many threads, you can just set `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to an acceptable number in your call to `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That's true I can do that, but the way `Parallel.ForEach` implements that is with a `Wait` on the running tasks.  I had hoped to avoid that because:

`Wait` uses `ManualResetEventSlim`, which tries a spinlock then reverts to a kernel Event object.

Creating a kernel Event object takes many instructions and a switch to kernel mode.

Waiting on a kernel Event object requires a switch to kernel mode.

Since I didn't have to do either of these things with my APM implementation, I was hoping there was some idiomatic TPL way that would avoid them as well.

Comment: When performing I/O, the last thing you need to worry about is "many instructions and a switch to kernel mode". But since `EndRead` also waits on an Event handle, I don't understand your concern.

Comment: I tried this in my own test harness, and I was surprised how minimal the penalty is for doing these sorts of waits.  

It's not the answer I wanted, but it seems right, so I'm accepting this answer.